# If foreign key doesn’t exists create and use it

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have two tables.
My first table is the `games` table, my second table is the `categories` table.
Every game has a category as a foreign key.

What I want is this: When adding a game with the SQL command (example: `insert into games(name, categoryId) values (‘gamename’, {here_category_id_by_name})`, if there is no such category, add it to the `categories` table and use the added id in the game query. If the category name already exists in the `categories` table, then use `categoryID` directly.

Additionally, how can I save this query as a function as I will be using it a lot?

Edit: **Only I can add data**. While adding data, I have more than one foreign key cell. I want to do the operation in a **single query**.
My tables: (“oyunlar” means **games**, “kategoriler” means **category**, “ad” means **name**)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. What happens if somebody mistypes a/the category? e.g. `sooter` instead of `shooter`. Do you add that category? Could you explain the logic behind your idea by hitting the [edit] link and adding to your question? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnK.N. I just edited and thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of this f.k, prevent someone from deleting a category that is in use by a game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the function for every table (i couldn't create dynamic function because concat function didn't work):

My "getref_myTableName" function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`emre`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getref_myTableName`(`deger` VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
declare iID int(11);
    Select komutID from komutlar where komutlar.komut = deger Into iID;
  IF FOUND_ROWS() = 0 THEN
    Insert Into komutlar(komut) Value (deger);
    Set iId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END IF;
return iID;
END
```

**Call:**

```
SET @id_for_myTable = getref_myTableName('myCategory');
select @id_for_myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with a **Trigger**.
Have it react to the insert on `games`, go check the `categories` table and, if required, insert the new category and use the [last_insert_id](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx) function to get the ID that new record.

All that said, I would question whether or not you *should*.

Categories suggest some sort of "structure" - every game is "one of" a particular category.  Do you *really* want new categories to be added all over the place?

Where do the category "names" come from?
If Users are allowed to enter them directly, you have the possibility of some very "questionable" categories being created!

Comment: W. I just edited question. I have 9x foreign key column in one table so I need best way to do this.

Comment: It is possible to turn off FKs and turn them back on.  Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Always do

```
INSERT INTO categories (name)
    VALUES (name)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The former inserts a new row if `name` is not already in the table.  And it returns the `id` for the existing *or* new row.  (Check the details; I may have something wrong.)

This could be done in your code, in a Stored Procedure wrapping the "new game", or in a Trigger.

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful. I created the function for every table (i couldn't create dynamic function because concat function didn't work):

"getref_kategori" function:

BEGIN
declare iID int(11);
    Select kategoriID From kategoriler where kategoriler.ad = deger Into iID;
  IF FOUND_ROWS() = 0 THEN
    Insert Into kategoriler(ad) Value (deger);
    Set iId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END IF;
return iID;
END

here is how I call it:
SET @id_kategori = getref_kategori('Online');
select @id_kategori;

Comment: @Dream59 - The `SELECT` is not needed.  Read more about IODKU.